# Database fetch all where exist something from other database table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 tables

```
First have id, fromid, post
Second have id, myid, userid
```

First is for all posts from all users

Second is for favorite users where myid shows id from user that made others as favorites and userid are id from favorited users

Now I want to output only posts from users that are in favorite table with myid

In words I would say output all posts where from id is equal to userid from second table where userid is connected to myid

I tried this but I am getting nothing.

```
$sqli = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE     
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM favppl WHERE myid='$username' AND userid!='$username')";
```

OR Question like this:
I want to select all from post table and check does fromid from post table is somewhere in favppl table in userid field connected with myid which is equal to something

Comment: Have your run the subquery alone to verify it is returning rows?

Comment: Yeah alone it works everything..

Comment: Is `userid` perhaps numeric? Please show us a bit of data and/or schema.

Comment: it is not it is md5 from string

Comment: Too many possibilities to guess. Please show some data and schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the id which is going to find the pair in the other table.
I wrote the correct query here. You can use your desired id field names.
I supposed the column 'myid' keeps the post ids

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE     
id IN (SELECT myid FROM favppl WHERE myid='$postId' AND userid!='$username')
```

Comment: @Skyey. Glad to help. No problem